# How to combine columns, group them then get a total count?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Below is a table that has candidate_id, two interviews they attended with the interviewer's name, and results for each interview.

| candidate_id | interview_1 | interview_2 | result_1 | result_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Interviewer_A | Interviewer_B | Pass | Pass |
| 2 | Interviewer_C | Interviewer_D | Pass | Reject |

I need help to combine column interview_1 and interview_2 into one column, and count how many pass and reject each interviewer gave to the candidate, the result I expected to see as below:

| interviewer_name | pass_count | reject_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Interviewer_A | 1 | 0 |
| Interviewer_B | 1 | 0 |
| Interviewer_C | 1 | 0 |
| Interviewer_D | 0 | 1 |

SQL or Python either would work for me! Much appreciated!

Comment: Is it a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, it becomes a small matter for a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Select [candidate_id]
      ,B.[Interview_name]
      ,pass_count   = case when result='Pass' then 1 else 0 end
      ,reject_count = case when result='Pass' then 0 else 1 end
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ([interview_1],[result_1])
                     ,([interview_2],[result_2])
             ) B(Interview_name,result)
```

**Results**

```
candidate_id    Interview_name  pass_count  reject_count
1               Interviewer_A   1           0
1               Interviewer_B   1           0
2               Interviewer_C   1           0
2               Interviewer_D   0           1
```

Comment: Gets my vote, but arguably it would be a bit simpler if the table value constructor just returned the raw result and your case expression was in the outer select rather than repeated for each row of the table value constructor. Entirely subjective of course, and no more or less correct either way

Comment: @GarethD  You are correct,  I did consider a simple logic switch for pass/reject after I actually saw the redundant case expression.   Let's call this a lazy copy paste ..  I will add the thinner version

Comment: Thank you so much! I use SQL Server too, but I am not familiar with CROSS APPLY. Much appreciated!

Comment: @PeachKiller Happy to help.  CROSS APPLY can be invaluable.  Well worth a little time experimenting with it.   I think of it as a sub-routine at the record level.   Also a nice benefit is that you can STACK reusable calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the dataset twice and union together, I'm assuming it's not an unwieldy set.

Something like -

```
WITH combined_set AS(
SELECT
 candidate_id,
 interviewer_1 as interviewer,
 result_1 as result
from candidate_table

UNION

SELECT
 candidate_id,
 interviewer_2 as interviewer,
 result_2 as result
from candidate_table)

SELECT
 interviewer,
 count(case when result = 'Pass' then 1 end) as pass_count,
 count(case when result = 'Reject' then 1 end) as reject_count
FROM combined_set
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried this way originally, but there are like 20 columns for interviews and another 20 columns for results.....

Comment: Not as familiar with python, but if your data sizes change I'd imagine you could write some code to grab the max interview count and then run a for loop to stack the columns that starts by grabbing the index of the first interview column and that index + the max and go from there to aggregate it, or have the loop tagged to grab [interview_i] and [results_i] and end on i > max